# Multiple output of bootstrap in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function M file defined as follows:

```
function [v,m ] = myfun(y)
m=mean(y);
v=var(y);
end
```

For a given vector which consists of integers from 1 to 100 for simplicity, I want to do bootstrap for 10 times and obtain both mean and variance for each bootstrapped sample. The following wouldn't work:

```
y=[1:100]';
[m,v]=bootstrp(10,@(x) myfun(x),y);
```

Could any one help me out of here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EugeneK - Not necessarily.  You can provide your own anonymous functions to this input, as well as specifying function handles.  I do agree that `@(x) myfun(x)` is superfluous and you can simply use `@myfun`, but the meaning is still the same and it'll still work.

Comment: Thanks Eugene! I got an error message saying that there are too many output arguments. I think @(x) myfun(x) is fine.

Comment: @rayryeng. My actual function have multiple inputs, the first being data to be bootstrapped, and others being some prespecified variables. This is why I use @(x). This example is simply for illustration purpose.

Comment: @Pittance - Not a problem.  Assuming those pre-defined variables are static every time you call the custom function, the error message can be solved if you read the amendment to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you think it works?  This does exactly what you're specifying.  However, I would do away with specifying a separate function and putting the mean and standard deviation directly in the anonymous function itself.  Specifically:

```
stats = bootstrp(10, @(x) [mean(x) var(x)], y);
```

In this case, you will get a 10 x 2 matrix.  The first column will give you the mean of each boostrapped sample while the next column will give you the variance of each bootstrapped sample.  Specifically, the first row gives you the mean (first column) and variance (second column) of the first sample.  The second row gives you the mean and variance of the second sample, and so on.  Each column of your output in `stats` will give you whatever measure you are calculating in the corresponding position in the output vector of your function.

Check the documentation for `bootstrp` here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootstrp.html

---

To answer your question as to why you're getting the too many outputs error is because you need to output only **one variable**, but you are outputting two.  As such, group your variables into a single vector like so:

```
function [out] = myfun(y)
m=mean(y);
v=var(y);
out = [m,v];
end
```

If you now run your `bootstrp` code with this function, it should now work.

Comment: Thanks rayreng! I've got back from my office and don't have matlab with me right now. Will check your solution tomorrow! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, @rayryeng, jut want to let you know that the codes you suggested work out now. I appreciate your help! Have a nice day!